# Appropriate test for two not-normally-distributed data samples

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have some data comparing training participants who experienced the same training course either face-to-face or virtually (via Zoom). I have two survey items I am comparing. Sample A is for virtual delivery and has 186 participants, and sample B is for face-to-face delivery and has 100 participants. I have the raw data and can compute means, standard deviation, etc. What is the appropriate text of statistical difference? Student's T-Test or Wilcoxin/Mann-Whitney?

Complicating the matter is that the samples were taken at different time periods, roughly pre-COVID and during COVID. I.e, July to December 2019 versus July to December 2020. I appreciate that my samples are more convenience, there is no randomisation to condition, etc. But this is a real-world opportunity to compare the differences. Any thoughts on this?

Thanks for your guidance!

Gene Johnson

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you want to compare? Both tests you mentioned examine differences in means while not being concerned about much else (it's more complicated than this, but both have solid properties when they are used to detect differences in means).

Comment: Two survey items. Unfortunately we changed specific survey items over that time period. We do have two identical items: one on clarity of learning objectives, and one on facilitator's enhancement of experience. Fortunately they reflect two important aspects of the training experience.

Comment: What about those survey responses?

Comment: They are Likert-scaled, agree to disagree. So I can compare mean responses for each group.

Comment: What are you trying to answer, whether there is a statistical difference in test scores between the two groups?

Comment: Yes, whether there is a statistical differences in mean ratings between the two groups

Comment: You can use a t-test to answer exactly this.